# Flask / Whoosh full text search just redirecting me to index

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-whooshee

I'm using Flask.ext.WhooshAlchemy, a `Flask` wrapper for the Whoosh full text indexing & searching library.I have an index page with a search form on it, and this is the relevant part of the `views.py` :

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    posts = [i for i in Email.query.all()]
    return render_template('index.html',  
                           title='Home',
                           posts=posts,
                           search_form=g.search_form)

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.search_form = SearchForm()

@app.route('/cruz')
def cruz():
    u = Politician.query.get(1)
    num = len(u.emails.all())
    posts = u.emails.all()
    return render_template('cruz.html',title='Ted Cruz',posts=posts,num=num)

from config import MAX_SEARCH_RESULTS

@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
def search():
    if not g.search_form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return redirect(url_for('search_results', query=g.search_form.search.data))

@app.route('/search_results/<query>')
def search_results(query):
    results = Email.query.whoosh_search(query, MAX_SEARCH_RESULTS).all()
    return render_template('search_results.html',
                           query=query,
                           results=results)
```

This is the HTML I'm using to show the search form   :

```
  <form style="display: inline;" action="{{ url_for('search') }}" method="post" name="search">{{ g.search_form.hidden_tag() }}{{ g.search_form.search(size=20) }}<input type="submit" value="Search"></form>
```

I've tried both using and not using the flask global g, taking off and applying different handlers, but nothing seems to work.  Whenever I enter text into the search field and hit enter, a request is made but it just ultimately redirects to index.

small update: I switched around a few things in the `view.py`, like more directly referring to the form in the search function. All changes are now reflected in the current post.  Now, when I enter in searches, it still routes me back to the index, but doesn't show the CSRF token in the URL - instead, it just shows `/?search=QUERY`.  I think the problem lies in the redirects part of the search function of `views.py`, but no matter what I change it to (like `render_template`) it still loops me back to index. Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?